# Push Notification option is not visible on microsoft dashboard services

Tags: push-notification, uwp, windows-10, wns

For implementing notification on my app I have followed "Register your app for the Windows Store" in  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification)

But when doing so I cant see Push Notification link under services. Services includes Xbox Live, Experimentation, Maps, product collections and purchases link only. What is the reason for it? How can I enable Push Notification link on Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **WNS/MPNS** page is now under **App Management** tab.

However, the main part of the setup (retrieving the app secret key) is then under the *Live services site* link. This will lead you to your app's page on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and you will be able to get the secret key and package SID there.